# Quartic function in four variables

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1^2+ y_1^4+x_2^4+y_2^2+ 8x_1x_2+8y_1y_2\\ \text{subject to} & x_1+y_1=1\\ & x_2+y_2=1\end{array}$$

Is the function convex/ strictly convex?

For critical points:

I did $f_{x_1}= 2x_1+8x_2=0$; $f_{x_2}=4x_2^3+8x_1=0$; $f_{y_1}=4y_1^3+8y_2=0$; $f_{y_2}=2y_2+8y_1=0$

This gives $x_2=0, 2\sqrt{2}, x_1=0, -8\sqrt{2}$, same will be for $y_1, y_2$, could anyone tell me what next?

Lagrange multiplier corresponding to the problem:

$L(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2, \lambda, \mu)= x_1^2+ y_1^4+x_2^4+y_2^2+ 8x_1x_2+8y_1y_2 + \lambda (x_1+y_1-1)+ \mu(x_2+y_2-1)$

$L_{x_1}= 2x_1+8x_2+\lambda=0$;

$L_{x_2}=4x_2^3+8x_1+\mu=0$;

$L_{y_1}=4y_1^3+8y_2+\lambda=0$;

$L_{y_2}=2y_2+8y_1+\mu=0$

$L_{\lambda}=x_1+y_1-1=0$

$L_{\mu}=x_2+y_2-1=0$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you substituted those values in to see what value you get?

Comment: Presumably you're trying to do Lagrange multiplier? If yes, is that the correct setup?

Comment: Sure, edit your work into the question. What is the lagrange multipler L to consider?

Comment: Yes. The $L$ function is the one that you're supposed to differentiate and solve, not the $f$ function. Can you proceed?

Comment: What do you think the next steps in Lagrange Multipliers are?

Comment: Hint: You did it previously (but to the wrong function).

Comment: Right, you solve the system. Equate the lambdas/mius to each other (and then hope for the best). That's the downside of LM, which is the resultant system might be ugly to manually manipulate (Disclaimer, I've not tried to solve it as yet.)

Comment: I used WolframAlpha as a quick way to check whatever result you come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not convert your equality constrained problem into an unconstrained problem.
\begin{align}
x_1 + y_1 = 1 \tag{C1} \label{C1} \\
x_2 + y_2 = 1 \tag{C2} \label{c2}
\end{align}
Now if we set $x_1 = z_1$, then to satisfy \ref{C1} we must set $y_1 = 1 - z_1$. Similary if we set $x_2 = z_2$ we must set $y_2 = 1-z_2$ to satisfy \ref{c2}. Inserting for $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ yields the unconstrained problem
$$
\arg \min g(z_1, z_2)
$$ 
where
\begin{equation}
g(z_1, z_2) = z_1^2 + (1-z_1)^4 + z_2^4 + (1-z_2)^2 + 8 z_1 z_2 + 8(1-z_1)(1-z_2).
\end{equation}
We evaluate the gradient of $g$,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1} &= 2 z_1 - 4(1-z_1)^3 + 8 z_2 - 8(1-z_2)\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_2} &= 4z_2^3 - 2(1-z_2) + 8z_1 -8(1-z_1)
\end{align}
and use it to find the critical points of $g$ as the solutions to the nonlinear system
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1} &= 2 z_1 - 4(1-z_1)^3 + 8 z_2 - 8(1-z_2) = 0 \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_2} &= 4z_2^3 -2 (1-z_2) + 8z_1 -8(1-z_1) = 0 
\end{align}
Because I'm lazy I solve this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%222%20x%20-%204%281-x%29%5E3%20%2B%208y%20-%208%281-y%29%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%224y%5E3%20-%202%281-y%29%20%2B8x%20-%208%281-x%29%22). It has the real solutions $$(z_1, z_2) \in \{(-0.601, 1.601), (0.544, 0.456), (3.056, -2.056)\}.$$
We can compute 
\begin{align}
&g(-0.601, 1.601) = -7.46 \\
&g(0.544, 0.456) = 5.31 \\
&g(3.056, -2.056) = -72.32
\end{align}
To classify these critical points we can compute the Hessian and check whether it is symmetric positive definite (or semidefinite). I instead use [Wolfram again](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2B%20%281-x%29%5E4%20%2B%20y%5E4%20%2B%20%281-y%29%5E2%20%2B%208%20xy%20%2B%208%281-x%29%281-y%29%20from%20x%20%3D-1%20to%204%20and%20y%3D-3%20to%202) and visually inspect that $(3.056, -2.056)$ is a local minimum. As our function is coercive I conclude that this also is a global minimum.